# Jasper Report with Struts2 Framework

Tags: jsp, struts2, jasper-reports

I've created an application in `Struts2` framework with `Jasper` reporting.

In the index page when I click a button then I will get report as pdf displayed.

But I'm very much concerned about my implementation. Does the implementation what I did is the correct way?

Since I noticed in several tutorials that calling jasper in struts2 is somewhat like:

```
  <action name="myJasperTest" class="com.acme.test.action.JasperAction">
        <result name="success" type="jasper">
            <param name="location">/jasper/our_compiled_template.jasper</param>
            <param name="dataSource">myList</param>
            <param name="format">PDF</param>
        </result>
  </action>
```

but i don't know how to pass parameter to query with the above way?
can anyone please tell me some solutions or suggestions

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <s:form action="getUserDetails"  method="post">
            <s:submit value="Show" onclick="this.form.target='_blank';return true;"/>           
        </s:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JasperReport.java**

```
package commonpackage;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader;
import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;

public class JasperReport extends ActionSupport
{
     private String userid="1";
     public InputStream inputStream;
      public String getUserDetails() throws ClassNotFoundException{

            try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ortms", "root", "");
            String str;
            str = ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/reports/myreport.jrxml");
            JasperDesign jd=JRXmlLoader.load(str);
            Map parameters = new HashMap();
            parameters.put("userid", userid);
            net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
            JasperPrint jp=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, parameters,cn);
            JRExporter exporter = new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jp);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/reports/myreport.pdf"));
            exporter.exportReport();
            File file = new File(ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/reports/myreport.pdf"));  
            inputStream = new DataInputStream( new FileInputStream(file));

            return SUCCESS;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in getUserDetails in JasperReport class");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

   return SUCCESS;
}

      public void setInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }



public InputStream getInputStream() {
        return inputStream;
    }
}
```

**struts.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <include file="example.xml"/>
    <!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
      <action name="getUserDetails" class="commonpackage.JasperReport" method="getUserDetails">
         <result name="success" type="stream">
           <param name="contentType">application/pdf</param>
           <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
           <param name="contentDisposition">inline;filename="UserReport.pdf"</param>
           <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
         </result>
      </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**myreport.jrmxl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report name" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="70b2040b-a566-48b5-8e8e-a01d402007e3">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="userid" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
     table_users.`id` AS table_users_id,
     table_users.`user_code` AS table_users_user_code,
     table_users.`first_name` AS table_users_first_name,
     table_users.`last_name` AS table_users_last_name
FROM
     `table_users` table_users WHERE table_users.`id`=$P{userid}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="table_users_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="table_users_user_code" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="table_users_first_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="table_users_last_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="ca3f2664-22a6-4f31-b04b-f61b774d2dc3" x="33" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="ca3f2664-22a6-4f31-b04b-f61b774d2dc3" x="132" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[CODE]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="ca3f2664-22a6-4f31-b04b-f61b774d2dc3" x="232" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[FIRST NAME]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="ca3f2664-22a6-4f31-b04b-f61b774d2dc3" x="332" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[LAST NAME]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="095242c4-b1b5-4545-897c-315f3bbe37a2" x="33" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{table_users_id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="095242c4-b1b5-4545-897c-315f3bbe37a2" x="133" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{table_users_user_code}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="095242c4-b1b5-4545-897c-315f3bbe37a2" x="232" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{table_users_first_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="095242c4-b1b5-4545-897c-315f3bbe37a2" x="332" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{table_users_last_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 1):

Regards to the Document, you should do this:

```
reportParameters - (2.1.2+) OGNL expression used to retrieve a map of report 
parameters from the value stack. The parameters may be accessed in the report 
via the usual JR mechanism and might include data not part of the dataSource, 
such as the user name of the report creator, etc.
```

So you should have this configuration:

```
<action name="myJasperTest" class="com.acme.test.action.JasperAction">
        <result name="success" type="jasper">
            <param name="location">/jasper/our_compiled_template.jasper</param>
            <param name="dataSource">myList</param>
            <param name="format">PDF</param>
            <param name="exportParameters">parameterMap</param>
        </result>
  </action>
```

Here is the [Document](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/jasperreports-plugin.html)

Comment: what about the case of dataSource? in the case i've nothing to return as arraylist

Comment: @user2040500 in your case, `myList` should be a list of object, whose objects contains following attributes: `ID`, `CODE`, `FIRSTNAME`, `LASTNAME`, these are all on your report.jrxml